# ASP.net Web.Config Redirect Rules

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I am having an issue with this redirect. I am trying to permanently redirect each state's installation location page to the new one. This is one example and it works fine.

```
<rule name="49 set wyoming/installation-locations 301 permanently moved" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="wyoming/installation-locations" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/locations/wy/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Now when I have to redirect the main installation-locations page (below) it works, but this new redirect rule overwrites the one above and the ones for every other state.

```
<rule name="locations redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="installation-locations" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/locations/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: We solved this by placing Response.Redirect("/locations"); server side script directly on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by placing server side script in the skin of the page.

```
if (DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.CurrentPage.TabName == "Installation Locations")
Response.Redirect("/locations");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try settings the pattern to accept nothing else before the `installation-locations` of the `locations redirect` rule.

```
<rule name="locations redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(installation-locations)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/locations/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the most easily way to solve it is modify the url rewrite rule order.

Since the installation-locations could also match the "wyoming/installation-locations" pattern, you will find the locations redirect rule is useless.

As far as I know, the url rewrite rule match is one by one. It will use the first rule, then second, third. If the rule is match the first one, it will not coutinue match second.

I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule, it will work well.

```
 <rule name="49 set wyoming/installation-locations 301 permanently moved" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="wyoming/installation-locations" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/locations/wy/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
  <rule name="locations redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="installation-locations" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/locations/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I already tried doing this and it didn't work. We solved it different way. Thank you for your time, Brando!

Comment: I'm glad you have solved it. Could you please share the solution and mark it as answer? It will help other people who faces the same issue.

Comment: Roger that, Brando.